# How can I use AppleScript to type?

Tags: keyboard, applescript

How can I use AppleScript to type in a specified area on the screen? I've tried the `keystroke` command, but it doesn't seem to work. Also, how can I use AppleScript to display an image? Here is the code I have so far:

```
set theText to text returned of (display dialog "Put what you want to autotype here." default answer "" buttons {"OK", "cancel"} default button 1)
display dialog "select where you want me to type " & theText & " Your text will be typed in the area selected. you have 10 seconds to select once you click 'OK'" buttons {"OK"}
delay 10
say "typing"
--command for typing here
end
end
end
```

Comment: i think you need to learn to walk before you can run. Try a beginner's guide - http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-beginners-guide-to-applescript--mac-3436 or http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/index.html would be a fair start. Also, Ask Different is designed for one Question, one Answer. Multiple Questions need to be split. You also need to show what research you have done so far & what specific issue you are facing. Questions that are too broad will just be closed.

Comment: sorry, but that's not helpful a bit.

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve in the end using the script (e.g. what is this "specified area": a window, a dialog box, something else)? Also your script seems to be syntactically incorrect, is it taken out of a bigger script?

Answer (score 9):

```
tell application "System Events"
    set textToType to "text here"
    keystroke textToType
end tell
```

Replace within the quotes of "text here" to what ever you need.

Comment: Actually all the `delays` are not required. You can just use `keystroke "any text"` to write text and `keystroke return` to type the return key.

Comment: Put some warning on it it ruined some of my code :D next time I read a code before launching it.

Comment: Yeah seriously, why an infinite loop? Screwed up loads of code and stuff on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `key code` to type individual keys or achieve most functions using your keyboard.

```
key code 8 using {command down, shift down} --> ⌘+shift+C
```

Here is the full list of key codes:
https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes