# Open new application window via commandline

Tags: terminal, applications, shortcut

#### Background

If you need a new window of an app you can *right-click* the app in the dock and click `New Window`. This is very tedious and takes away precious time. I'd like to have a shortcut for that.

Currently I'm using *iCanHazShortcut*, which an run terminal commands from shortcuts. I currently use `open /Applications/Firefox.app --new` (Example). This opens a new instance of an application. I would generally have no problem with that if it wouldn't cripple the dock and the whole window manager over time. So:

#### Question

How can I open a new window of an application with a terminal command?

Constraints:

- If no application is running the command should of course create an instance of the app
- I'm not searching for a specific answer for my Firefox example in the top, but a generic approach (because I'm opening several different apps through shortcuts).

Comment: Do you want a different shortcut for *each* application? You should be abel to create a Service just using the AppleScript in the answer below, and then creating a key shortcut for that, without third-party apps or setting up new Terminal commands.

Comment: We probably have very different definition of "tedious" and "precious time". Opening  or navigating to Terminal, entering 10+ characters is tedious in my vocabulary. Especially when alternatively one can use Spotlight to open any application by entering couple of characters from beginning of it's name and if app is already opened then just adding cmd + n after app window is activated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line to your `~/.zshrc` file. (Or, your `~/.bashrc` file, if you are using bash.) If the file does not exist, then create the file.

```
openwin() { osascript -e "tell application \"$1\" to activate" -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using command down'; }
```

The next time you open a Terminal window, you will be able to use the above function to send the key combination <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to the application specified. For example, to open a new window in Firefox, enter the following.

```
openwin firefox
```

For Microsoft Edge, enter either of the following.

```
openwin "microsoft edge"
openwin microsoft\ edge
```

The key combination <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> is the default in most applications to open a new window.

When the above function is first used, you may need to do the following.

- Authorize the Terminal application to send Apple events to System Events. This can be found under Automation on the Privacy tab of the Security & Privacy pane of the System Preferences application.
- Allow `osascript` to send keystrokes. This is authorized by add the `Terminal` application to Accessibility on the Privacy tab of the Security & Privacy pane of the System Preferences application.

---

An alternative to using a function would be to install a script. This would have the advantage of being customizable. Below is an example script which is named `openwin`.

```
#!/bin/zsh
pgrep -i -x -q -U $UID "$1"
result=$? # If application is running then result will equal 0.
script=()
case ${1:l} in
mail)
    script+=(-e "tell application \"$1\" to activate")
    if [[ result -eq 0 ]]; then
        script+=(-e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using {command down, option down}')
    fi;;

"microsoft word")
    script+=(-e "tell application \"$1\" to activate")
    script+=(-e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using command down');;

*)
    script+=(-e "tell application \"$1\" to activate")
    if [[ result -eq 0 ]]; then
        script+=(-e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using command down')
    fi
esac
if [[ $#script -ne 0 ]]; then
    #printf "%s '%s'\n" $script # <-- Just for debugging.
    osascript $script
fi
```

Below are the commands to install the script. Here I assume `/usr/local/bin` is already in your `PATH` variable.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo cp openwin /usr/local/bin
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/bin/openwin
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/openwin
```

The default for the example script is to activate the application, then send the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> key combination only if the application is already running.

The example script has the following customizations.

- For the Mail application, the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> key combination is sent instead of the default <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.
- For the Microsoft Word application, the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> key combination is sent regardless of whether the application is running.

### References

- [AppleScript Command Sendkeys?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314647/applescript-command-sendkeys)
- [How can I use AppleScript to type?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194567/how-can-i-use-applescript-to-type)

Comment: Awesome! Note: I could not use the `openwin` command in `iCanHazShortcut`. I needed to write the full command there for each application I'm trying to open. E.g. `osascript -e "tell application \"firefox\" to activate" -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using command down';`.

Comment: @DarkTrick The script version in this answer should work for iCanHazShortcut.

Comment: Not for future reference: This commands leads to *opening two windows of the application* in some cases (perhaps, if it wasn't started already).

Comment: Thanks for the script version in preference to the function from .zshrc or .bashrc.  I always prefer standalone scripts to bloating up my shells with lots of unrelated functions, whenever possible.